# Issue with Material-UI Grid items

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having an issue getting the grid system to work properly for me. In one file I have this setup to render blog items:

```
    return (
    <div>
        {blogs != null
        ? (<Grid container direction="row" xs={12} md={4}>
                {blogs.map((blog) => {
                    console.log(blog);
                    return (
                        <div key={blog._id}>
                            <CardComp data={blog} />
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </Grid>)
        : ('loading....')}
    </div>
);
```

and in the card component file I have the following code:

```
    return (
       <Grid item direction="row">
           {data ? (
                   <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined" >
                       <CardContent>
                           <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
                               {blogs.title}
                           </Typography>
                           <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                               {renderDate(blogs.createdAt)}
                           </Typography>
                           <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
                               <p>{blogs.description.substring(0,200)}</p>
                           </Typography>
                       </CardContent>
                       <Grid container alignItems={"center"} alignContent={"space-between"} className={classes.bottom} >
                           <Grid item>
                               <CardActions>
                                   <Button size="small" variant={"outlined"}>Read More</Button>
                               </CardActions>
                           </Grid>
                           <Grid item>
                                   <Grid container justify={"space-between"}>
                                       {blogs.tags.slice(0,3).map((tag, index) => {
                                           return(
                                               <>
                                                   <Button variant={"outlined"} color={"primary"} size={"small"}>{tag}</Button>
                                               </>
                                           )
                                       })}
                                   </Grid>
                           </Grid>
                       </Grid>
                   </Card>
               )
               :('Loading....')}
       </Grid>
);
```

As you can see above, I set the container and direction to the object before the .map render. Yet everything renders as below:
[image: Bug screen]

Comment: Consider using a 2 space indentation on highly nested code blocks. It makes the code more readable which increases your chances of a quick answer. An online prettifier/formatter can do that for you automatically.

Comment: Try putting your grid and grid container in the same component. Your grid container should come after you’re mapping and your grid item will wrap your card component. Also the answer someone provided is key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the component size of the card to be displayed on `<Grid Item>`. NOT on `<Grid Container>`.

**To fix your code change:**

`<Grid container direction="row" xs={12} md={4}>`

to

`<Grid container direction="row">`

**and change:**

`<Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined" >`

to

`<Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined"  xs={12} md={4}>`

---

Check the docs and click on the expand icon to see the examples: [Grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#basic-grid)

From the docs. Basic grid, press on <> icon on the bottom to expand the source code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
}));

export default function CenteredGrid() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Grid item>` must be inside .map

```
<Grid container>
   data.map(item => (
     <Grid item key={item.id} xs=12} md={4}> 
        <>
        {item.text}
        </>
     </Grid>
    ))
</Grid>
```